# Run/drive Excel via own application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com-automation

Is it possible to 'drive' excel via a c# application (i.e. select something from a excel gui dropdown list, press a button and read the content of particular cells)?

This is not really for testing but for data scrapping similarly to selenium where you can drive a browser via C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to 'drive' excel via a c# application (i.e. select something from a excel gui dropdown list, press a button and read the content of particular cells)?

Yes, you can use COM Automation from C#. Create a C# project and add a reference in the COM section of the dialog. You should reference *Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library*. This is the Excel 2010 version and if you use another version you should reference the version you have installed on your machine.

You can then automate Excel in a similar way as you would do using VBA except you now are using C#. On MSDN you have [Getting Started with VBA in Excel 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx) that among other things explain how you can use the macro recorder to create a VBA subroutine from actions you perform in Excel. You then have to translate the VBA into similar C# code.